# android Eclipse logcat error: device() request rejected - device not found

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I am having trouble getting my somewhat new Thunderbolt to print to logcat in eclipse...when I plug it in, I get the following error in the console:

```
[2011-08-04 11:23:10 - DeviceMonitor]Failed to start monitoring 
[2011-08-04 11:23:11 - Logcat]device () request rejected: device not found
java.io.IOException: device () request rejected: device not found
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Unknown Source)

at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can run adb just fine, and sometimes when I totally restart my computer logcat will work for a while, but it usually doesn't.  Makes it hard to debug!

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try typing the following using adb (either from the adb.exe directory or after adding adb to your environment variables):

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

See if this works.

EDIT:

It looks like the device is not installed on your system.

This means you need to install the manufacturer's device drivers.

The entire list can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html).

The driver for your Thunderbolt can be found [here](http://dl4.htc.com/RomCode/Source_and_Binaries/USB_driver_20101122_release.zip).

Install these and restart your computer if needed, and give it a try again.

Comment: No, that's not fixing the problem.  Thanks, though!

Comment: Try "adb devices" in cmd to list devices to see if they are even connected.

Comment: yea, I've tried that and I get this:


List of devices attached 
 device

Comment: This means that your device is not recognized in the system.
I have revised my answer to suit this, check it please.

Comment: OK that's good for a start, thank you.  I forgot to mention I'm developing on a mac..it looks like HTC doesn't support Sync for Mac OSX.  The only drivers I can find are .exe

Comment: ah, according to the Android documentation, you shouldn't need any drivers for Mac.  I would make sure USB debugging is turned on and making sure unsigned applications are allowed on the phone.  Both of these should be in settings on your phone.